# Langchain Routerchain (Retrieval-, Defaultchain) Problem with more then 1 input variable

Tags: langchain, huggingface, large-language-model

I am currently trying to implement a router chain in Langchain with two "sub-chains" - retrieval chain and standard LLM chain.
I have encountered the problem that my retrieval chain has two inputs and the default chain has only one input.
Therefore, I started the following experimental setup.

```
    class MultitypeDestRouteChain(MultiRouteChain) :
        """A multi-route chain that uses an LLM router chain to choose amongst prompts."""
    
        router_chain: RouterChain
        """Chain for deciding a destination chain and the input to it."""
        destination_chains: Mapping[str, Chain]
        """Map of name to candidate chains that inputs can be routed to."""
        default_chain: LLMChain
        """Default chain to use when router doesn't map input to one of the destinations."""
    
        @property
        def output_keys(self) -> List[str]:
            return ["text"]
            
            
            
    DB_FAISS_PATH = 'vectorstores/db_faiss'
    
    def load_llm():
        llm = LlamaCpp(
                model_path="../models/openbuddy-llama2-13b-v11.1.Q4_K_M.gguf"  ,
                max_tokens=2048,
                n_ctx= 4096,
                n_threads= 0,
                n_batch=512,
                top_p=0.7,
                top_k=20,
                repeat_penalty=1.15,
                temperature = 0.7,
                n_gpu_layers = 32,
            )
        return llm
    

template_general = """SYSTEM: Example template


USER: {input}
ASSISTANT:
"""

    
    
    template_specific = """Example template 
    
    Context: {context}
    Question: {question}
    
    """
    
    def set_custom_prompt():
        """
        Prompt template for QA retrieval for each vector stores
        """
    
        prompt = PromptTemplate(template=template2, input_variables=['context', 'question'])
        
        return prompt
    
    
    #Retrieval QA Chain
    def retrieval_qa_chain(llm, prompt, db):
        qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm,
                                           chain_type='stuff',
                                           retriever=db.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'k': 2}),
                                           return_source_documents=True,
                                           chain_type_kwargs={'prompt': prompt}
                                           )
        return qa_chain
    
    #QA Model Function
    def qa_bot():
        embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name="sentence-transformers/paraphrase-multilingual-MiniLM-L12-v2",
                                           model_kwargs={'device': 'cpu'})
        db = FAISS.load_local(DB_FAISS_PATH, embeddings)
        llm = load_llm()
        qa_prompt = set_custom_prompt()
        qa = retrieval_qa_chain(llm, qa_prompt, db)
    
        return qa
    
    #output function
    def final_result(query):
        qa_result = qa_bot()
        response = qa_result({'query': query})
        return response
    
    prompt_infos = [
        {
            "name": "llm_chain_general",
            "description": "Good for answering questions about general knwoledge",
            "prompt_template": template_general,
        },
        {
            "name": "llm_chain_specific",
            "description": "Good for answering special questions local data ",
            "prompt_template": template_specific,
        },
    ]
    
    destination_chains = {}
    
    prompt_general = PromptTemplate(template=template_general, input_variables=["input"])
    llm_chain_general = LLMChain(prompt=prompt_general, llm=llm)
    
    
    destination_chains["llm_chain_general"] = llm_chain_general
    destination_chains["llm_chain_specific"] = llm_chain_specific
    
    
    destinations = [f"{p['name']}: {p['description']}" for p in prompt_infos]
    destinations_str = "\n".join(destinations)
    
    router_template = MULTI_PROMPT_ROUTER_TEMPLATE.format(destinations=destinations_str)
    router_prompt = PromptTemplate(
        template=router_template,
        input_variables=['input'],
        output_parser=RouterOutputParser(),
    )
    router_chain = LLMRouterChain.from_llm(llm, router_prompt)
    default_chain = ConversationChain(llm=llm, output_key="text")
    
    chain = MultitypeDestRouteChain (
        router_chain=router_chain,
        destination_chains=destination_chains,
        default_chain=default_chain,
        verbose=True,
    )
    
result = chain("This would be a question for example chain?")   #This is not working i get an error
result = chain("This would be a question for general chain?")   #This is working
result = llm_chain_specific("This would be a question for example chain?") #This is working
result = llm_chain_general("This would be a question for general chain?") #This is working
    
    
    print(result['text'])
```

I get the following error message:

```
    Entering new MultitypeDestRouteChain chain...
    /home/zuiwer/miniconda3/envs/chainlit/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/chains/llm.py:280: UserWarning: The predict_and_parse method is deprecated, instead pass an output parser directly to LLMChain.
      warnings.warn(
    /home/zuiwer/miniconda3/envs/chainlit/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/generation/utils.py:1417: UserWarning: You have modified the pretrained model configuration to control generation. This is a deprecated strategy to control generation and will be removed soon, in a future version. Please use a generation configuration file (see https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/text_generation )
      warnings.warn(
    llm_chain_specific: {'input': 'This would be a question for example chain?'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/zuiwer/miniconda3/envs/chainlit/bin/chainlit", line 8, in <module>
        sys.exit(cli())
                 ^^^^^
      File "/home/zuiwer/miniconda3/envs/chainlit/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
        return this.main(*args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/zuiwer/miniconda3/envs/chainlit/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
        rv = this.invoke(ctx)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/zuiwer/miniconda3/envs/chainlit/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
        return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/zuiwer/miniconda3/envs/chainlit/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
        return ctx.invoke(this.callback, **ctx.params)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/zuiwer/miniconda3/envs/chainlit/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
        return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/zuiwer/miniconda3/envs/chainlit/lib/python3.11/site-packages/chainlit/cli/__init__.py", line 152, in chainlit_run
        run_chainlit(target)
      File "/home/zuiwer/miniconda3/envs/chainlit/lib/python3.11/site-packages/chainlit/cli/__init__.py", line 45, in run_chainlit
        load_module(config.run.module_name)
      File "/home/zuiwer/miniconda3/envs/chainlit/lib/python3.11/site-packages/chainlit/config.py", line 247, in load_module
        spec.loader.exec_module(module)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib
```

General Chain and specific chains are working fine.
And also general chain in RuterChain is working fine.
But Retrieval Chain has a problem probably because of 2 inputs.
If somebody would have a solution, i would be really gratefull.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple input variable it must need to pass through zod, as in routerChain (you don't need to write sequencialChain)

```
let routerParser = RouterOutputParser.fromZodSchema(z.object({
    destination: z
        .string()
        .describe('name of the prompt to use or "DEFAULT"'),
    next_inputs: z.object({
        input: z
            .string()
            .describe('input'),
        context: z
            .string()
            .describe('context') 
    })
}))
let routerFormat = routerParser.getFormatInstructions();

// Now we can construct the router with the list of route names and descriptions
let routerPrompt = new PromptTemplate({
    template: routerTemplate,
    inputVariables: ['input','context'],
    outputParser: routerParser,
    partialVariables: {
        format_instructions: routerFormat
    }
});
```

You need to make it usable in python but this logic will surely works well :)